# Serialize struct fields to pre existing slice of bytes

Tags: go, serialization

I have a setup where I receive data over the network and serialize it to my struct. It works fine, but now I need to serialize the data to a slice buffer to send it across the network.

I am trying to avoid having to allocate more than needed so I have already set up a buffer which I like to write to for all my serializing. But am not sure how to do this.

My setup is like this:

```
recieveBuffer := make([]byte, 1500)
header := recieveBuffer[0:1]
message := recieveBuffer[1:]
```

So I am trying to write fields from a struct to `message` and the total number of bytes for all the fields as a value for `header`.

This was how I deserialized to the struct:

```
// Deserialize ...
func (userSession *UserSession) Deserialize(message []byte) {
    userSession.UID = int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(message[0:4]))
    userSession.UUID = string(message[4:40])
    userSession.Username = string(message[40:])
}
```

I don't really know how to do the reverse of this, however. Is it possible without creating buffers for each field I want to serialize before copying to `message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the preallocated buffer `buf`, you can reverse the process like this:

```
buf[0] = byte(40+len(userSession.Username))
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buf[1:], uint32(int32(userSession.UID)))
copy(buf[5:41], userSession.UUID)
copy(buf[41:], userSession.Username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two helper functions.

One to encode a primitive to a byte slice:

```
func EncodeNumber2NetworkOrder(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
   switch v.(type) {
   case int: // int is at least 32 bits
       b := make([]byte, 4)
       binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(v.(int)))
       return b, nil
   case int8:
       b := []byte{byte(v.(int8))}
       return b, nil
   // ... truncated
```

and one to convert primitive, non-byte slices to a byte slice

```
func EncodeBigEndian(in []float64) []byte {
   var out []byte = make([]byte, len(in)*8)
   var wg sync.WaitGroup

   wg.Add(len(in))
   for i := 0; i < len(in); i++ {
       go func(out *[]byte, i int, f float64) {
           defer wg.Done()
           binary.BigEndian.PutUint64((*out)[(i<<3):], math.Float64bits(f))
       }(&out, i, in[i])
   }
   wg.Wait()

   return out
}
```

your binary serialization might look like this for a bogus struct like

```golang
 type Foo struct {
     time int64
     data []float64
 }

 func Encode(f *Foo) []byte {
    da := encoder.EncodeBigEndian(f.data)
    bytes := make([]byte,0)
    bytes = append(bytes, da...)
    return bytes
 }
```